# SVG: relatedTarget.correspondingUseElement is undefined in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, svg

I have the following HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<div id="body">
    <svg version="1.1" ...>
        <defs>
            <svg id="svgelid" width="24" height="24" x="0" y="0" version="1.1">
                <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#282828" .../>
                <text pointer-events="none" ...>X</text>
            </svg>
        </defs>
        <g id="wrapper">
            <svg version="1.1" id="element" width="24" height="24" ...>
                <use id="useid" href="#svgelid" ...>
            </svg>
        </svg>
    </svg>
</div>
```

and JavaScript code:

```js
document.getElementById('body').addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) { // and then mouseout
    ...
});
```

If I hover over the #element SVG the `e.relatedTarget` in that eventListener points to <rect> element inside <defs>. I need to get the #element SVG element.

I tried: `e.relatedTarget.correspondingUseElement.parentNode` and it works fine in Firefox/Chrome but not in IE (I have tested IE 9 and 11). The `e.relatedTarget.correspondingUseElement` is undefined in IE and `e.relatedTarget.parentNode` is #svgelid element, so the one inside <defs>.

I also tried `e.relatedTarget.ownerSVGElement` and again - it works good on Firefox/Chrome but not on Internet Explorer which gives me #svgelid element.

Can anyone tell me why is `e.relatedTarget.correspondingUseElement` undefined in Internet Explorer?

Comment: correspondingUseElement works fine in Firefox? I don't think so, it's not implemented there.

Comment: Yes, you're right, my bad with explanation - e.relatedTarget returns USE element in Firefox, e.relatedTarget.correspondingUseElement in works in Chrome but I can't get any of it to work in IE, correspondingUseElement is implemented since IE9...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't answer your question but maybe I'm having a solution for your problem.
I'm not sure if this works for you but I'm having the same problem.
The problem is the following: In IE the object which triggers the event is e.g the rectangle whereas in FF/Chrome etc the `<use>` object itself triggers the event.
In my case the following code solves this problem:

```
    var target = e.target
    var original;
    if ((window.SVGElementInstance)&&(target instanceof SVGElementInstance))
    {
      original = target.correspondingElement;
      target = target.correspondingUseElement;
    }
    else
    {
      original = target;
    }
```

If you are now using `original` the object is the individual(rectangle and other shapes), and if you are using target the whole `use` object is used.
However this code is still buggy(scripts and browsers does not work fine with `<use>` tags) and some functions are still not working(e.g. stroking use objects in FF/Chrome etc). This is the only time IE works better than the other browsers^^